# How to vertically align a fraction and an answer blank

Tags: fractions

I am trying to typeset a worksheet where students will fill in things in blanks. In the below example, they will fill in what they multiply each of the fractions by to get a common denominator. However, the blanks are not aligned with the bottom of the fractions; they are too high. How could I move the fractions up (or resize them) or move the blanks down so that they are aligned?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$$\frac{1}{8}\cdot\underline{\hspace{1.5cm}}=\underline{\hspace{1.5cm}}
\hspace{1cm} 
\frac{7}{12}\cdot\underline{\hspace{1.5cm}}=\underline{\hspace{1.5cm}}$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `$$ … $$` for displayed equations. It's plan TeX syntax, and can yield bad vertical spacing.

Comment: @Bernard Good point. I corrected the code from the OP in my proposed solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a normal `\frac` command and use the `\phantom` approach (or use another blank space that works in math mode). `\phantom` occupies the space that would have been used by it's argument.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section*{Code Provided by OP}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{8}\cdot\underline{\hspace{1.5cm}}=\underline{\hspace{1.5cm}}
\hspace{1cm} 
\frac{7}{12}\cdot\underline{\hspace{1.5cm}}=\underline{\hspace{1.5cm}}
\end{equation}

\section*{Code Proposes by Manuel Kuehner}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{8} \cdot \frac{\phantom{123456}}{\phantom{123456}} =\frac{\phantom{123456}}{\phantom{123456}}
\hspace{1cm} 
\frac{7}{12} \cdot \frac{\phantom{123456}}{\phantom{123456}} =\frac{\phantom{123456}}{\phantom{123456}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\tobecompleted}{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{\underline{\hspace{1.5cm}}}}
\let\tbc\tobecompleted
\begin{document}

\[ \frac{1}{8} · \tbc = \tbc
  \hspace{1cm}
  \frac{7}{12} · \tbc = \tbc \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of declaring \newcommand{\tobecompleted} followed by let\tbc\tobecompleted?

Comment: Just to avoid a cryptic name for the command.